# Is it possible to check if an SMS number is blocked in twilio before sending it?

Tags: php, twilio, sms, twilio-api, twilio-php

I need a way to detect if a number is blocked by twilio from receiving SMS from my number or not(has opted out with a STOP command).

I am using the Lookups_Services_Twilio class from twilio-php-master api, but so far could not get the status, only country_code, national_format and other details from phone_numbers.get(). Are there any other classes/methods I should be looking for ?

```
require('twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php');
require('twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio/Rest/Lookups/PhoneNumber.php');

global $twilio_account_sid;
global $twilio_auth_token;

$client2 = new Lookups_Services_Twilio($twilio_account_sid, $twilio_auth_token);
$number = $client2->phone_numbers->get("+xxxxxxxxxxxxx");

$cc = $number->country_code;
$nf = $number->national_format;
```

Everything works up until here, but:

```
$status = $number->status;
```

returns nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Rafael, please share a Gist or similar, so that we can get a better understanding of what you're already doing.

Answer (score 1):

The lookup API does not this functionality, nor does any other Twilio API at the moment.

When a user sends STOP or a similar opt-out keyword, you will still receive this message at your messaging webhook, but you won't be able to send messages back from that point on. In this webhook, you should store the phone number that opted out in your own datastore for your own logic, to not send messages to it in the future.

If you do send a message to the phone number, Twilio will respond with [error 21610 - Attempt to send to unsubscribed recipient](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21610). You could handle this error as well by adding the phone number to the same datastore and not send messages to it in the future.

Comment: Allright, in this case I assume if the number ever sends a START command, that will reach our webhook and I can then set his status as receives_sms=true or something like that, right ? START always reaches the webhook as well.

Comment: @RafaelAnschau That is correct.